# Animation only works for the first click

Tags: android

I have `xxx` of type `ImageView`. If I click it, the event handler `animate` will be triggered to animate it.

```
public void animate(View view) {
    ImageView xxx= findViewById(R.id.xxx);
    xxx.animate().rotation(7200f).setDuration(3000);
}
```

It works only for the first click but for the subsequent clicks the animation does not work.

## Question

How to fix this issue?

Comment: is your method called for subsequent clicks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that `rotation` sets the rotation value to the provided float.
You are probably looking for `rotationBy` if you want to always rotate by that value